# How do I close an activity from another activity or bottomsheet dialog / fragmenr

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-fragmentactivity

Tried Using finish(), finishAfinity() and intent flag clear tasks.

//Activity A

```
public class A{
 public void finishActivity(){
     finish();
 }
}
```

//Activity B

```
 public class B{

 Activity a = new ActivityA();
     a.finishActivity();
}
```

I want Activity A to be closed by Activity B

Comment: Do you want to remove ActivityA from backstack?

Comment: No I don't want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use a broadcast receiver to close Activity A from Activity B. Calling Activity A from B using an object will result into a null pointer exception. This is because, when Activity B starts, Activity A's onPause() method is called.
> `Use BroadCastReceiver as below`

```
BroadCastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("finish_activity_a")) {
                // Finish activity
            }
        }
    };
```

> Then register your broadcast receiver as follows:

```
try {

        //Register BroadcastReceiver
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BroadCastActions.actionUpdateAppOptions));

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> You can register the broadcast receiver after initializing itin the onCreate method as above or in your onStart(), onResume(), onRestart() methods.
>
> To UnRegister your broadcast receiver, do a follows:

```
try {

    //Check If BroadCast Was Received
    if (broadcastReceiver != null) {

        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadCastReceiver);
    }

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

> You can UnRegister your broadcast receiver in the onCreate() method or onStop(), onPause(), onDestroy() methods.
> I hope thi one helps. Feel free to comment below. Good Luck!